# Creating a simple csv with synthetic data - Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm learning python and machine learning and trying to create a very simple csv from synthetic data.
Can anyone help me tweak this to get it to work in PyCharm?
I'm trying to input a random value from the selection in each column.
Much appreciated

```
import random
import pandas as pd


marriage_status = {'single', 'married', 'divorced', 'widowed', 'complicated'}
children = {'yes', 'no'}
employment = {'employed', 'self_employed', 'unemployed', 'student'}
income_abroad = {'yes', 'no'}
gender = {'M', 'F'}
response = {'refund', 'payment'}

columns = ['marriage_status', 'children', 'employment',
           'income_abroad', 'age', 'gender', 'income', 'expenses', 'response']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for i in range(1000):
    marriage_status = random.choice(list(marriage_status))
    children = random.choice(list(children))
    employment = random.choice(list(employment))
    income_abroad = random.choice(list(income_abroad))
    gender = random.choice(list(gender))
    response = random.choice(list(response))
    age = random.randint(18, 70)
    income = random.randint(0, 100000)
    expenses = random.randint(0, 10000)
    df = [marriage_status, children, employment, income_abroad, age, gender, income, expenses, response]

df[6].to_csv('taxfix_data.csv')
index = False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use pandas the easiest way is to do it like this

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"marriage_status" : ['single' ,'married', 'divorced', 'widowed', 'complicated],
"children" : ['yes', 'no'],
"employment" : ['employed', 'self_employed', 'unemployed', 'student'],
"gender" : ['M', 'F'],
"response" : ['refund', 'payment'],
"income_abroad" : ['yes', 'no']}
 index = [1, 2, 3])
```

Also here's a really useful cheatsheet for pandas  https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Comment: Hey, would this allow for a random choice of values for each column though?

Comment: Yes with this you can set the values to whatever you like you just need to change the info inside the brackets, if you want a random value  you can just setup a variable that gets a random value and set the brackets as that